# What is the type of a vector that stores a vector of one function and one vector of std::string

Tags: c++, string, function, vector

I am trying to figure a thing out right now and I can't, I need to find a type for this

(python)

```py
def fn1(hello: list[str]) -> None:
    pass

mv = [(fn1, ("1", "hello", "12", "no")), (fn1, ("w", "ufewef", "1ee", "no"))]  # any size
```

what is a C++ type for `mv`? (doesn't matter if it's mutable or not)

I tried `std::vector<std::vector<std::string, std::function>>` but it kelp throwing an error, is there a way to do it or will have to use two vectors?

Comment: I think you need a vector of structs. And define your own structs, something like struct my_data { std::function<void()> fn; std::string str1; ...  std::string str4; }; (and then give meaningful names to fn, str1, ... str4

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer thanks, I will try :)

Comment: Missing some parentheses. You probably mean `"no"))` at both spots.

Comment: @aschepler yes, sorry

Comment: `using MyFunction = void(const std::vector<std::string>&); using MyDataStructure = std::vector<std::pair<MyFunction*, std::vector<std::string>>>;` Or use `std::function<MyFunction>` in place of `MyFunction*` is you need to represent callables other than plain function pointer.

Comment: Guessing a little, but if the only need for the lists of strings is to pass each to the one corresponding function, then in both python and C++ you could also use closures aka lambdas to store just a list of callables which "know" their own data (python `List[Callable[[], None]]`, C++ `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types get complicated, so to make them shorter I'll first define a couple of type alias:

```
using StringVec = std::vector<std::string>;
using StringVecFunc = std::function<void(const StringVec&)>;
```

Now the type of your data container could be any of these:

```
using T1 = std::vector<std::tuple<StringVecFunc, StringVec>>;

using T2 = std::vector<std::pair<StringVecFunc, StringVec>>;

struct StringVecFuncAndArgs {
    StringVecFunc func;
    StringVec args;
};
using T3 = std::vector<StringVecFuncAndArgs>;
```

The big difference is how you access elements of the thing holding one function and one string-container (like the python tuples). For `std::tuple` you use `std::get<0>(t)` and `std::get<1>(t)` or `std::get<StringVecFunc>(t)` and `std::get<StringVec>(t)`. For `std::pair` you use `p.first` and `p.second`. For the custom struct you use `data.func` and `data.args`.

The `tuple` solution is maybe the most direct translation from the idea of a Python tuple. The `pair` is quick and easy if it doesn't need to be used from a lot of code. The custom struct solution takes the most work, but lets you give helpful names to the members.

Answer (score 1):

My program uses a `stringVec` **struct** that declares a `vector<string> hello` and a function that returns **void** `stringVecFunc`, which to use as an example prints the values of `hello`.

```
struct stringVec {
    vector<string> hello;
    void stringVecFunc();
};

void stringVec::stringVecFunc() {
    for (auto &x: hello) cout << x << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}
```

After this, a vector is responsible for storing data of type `stringVec` by this way:

```
stringVec stringVec1;
stringVec1.hello = {"hi", "hello", "hi", "hello"};

vector<stringVec> vec;
```

you can run a complete example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WEsKc67rc)